# Implementing a 301 redirect using the Next.js app router

Tags: next.js

I am using Next.js with app directory. I have a product page with the following URL structure: `/p/{id}/{name}`. My requirement is to fetch the corresponding product data and perform a server-side redirect using a 301 status code when a user accesses the URL `/p/{id}` to automatically redirect them to `/p/{id}/{name}`. I would appreciate guidance on how to accomplish this effectively.

I have attempted to use the `redirect()` method in Next.js, but it appears to be utilizing a 307 redirect code instead of the desired 301 code. As I require a 301 status code for the server-side redirect, I would like to seek advice on how to resolve this issue in a professional manner.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.